# Remove chrome v8 javascript engine function cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have dynamically load some html content in iframe, first I have load the following code this function load properly

```
<script>
function hi()
{
 debugger;
 alert("sample program");
}
</script>

<body>
<input type="button" onclick="hi();"></input>    
</body>
```

But second time just i remove the function definition and load to the iframe, but the old function result is display instead of "ReferenceError: hi is not defined" error

```
<script>

</script>

<body>
<input type="button" onclick="hi();"></input>    
</body>
```

See my program
http://jsfiddle.net/merbin2012/3p1wceqv/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is still a global function called hi defined.

```
>window.hi
function hi()
{
 debugger;
 alert("sample program");
}
```

You could get rid of the function:

```
window.hi = null;
```

Edit ----------------------------------------------------

Sorry didnt read the iframe part:

The browser is probably caching the page, you can trying to force it to reload, by changing the url to include the time:

```
<iframe src="subpage.html?_=1410772376349"/>
<iframe src="subpage.html?_=1410772384173"/>
```

Comment: I am using this function inside the "<iframe style="float:left;width:49%;height:450px;border: 1px solid green;" class="commonEditboxIframeClass" frameborder="0" id="iiffrraammee" name="editbox" noresize="noresize" src="javascript:'';"></iframe>
" then how can i set to null?